# Change css style depending on the url in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, url

I have the following css code:

```
.modern{
    display: none;
}
```

when the url contain 'modern' I would like to change '.modern display' to `normal`

Is that possible in Wordpress?

---

**EDIT:** I need to do this via Wordpress page console.

Comment: What "url"...the page you are on, a link in the HTML?  what?

Comment: `"normal"` isn't a `display` option...In any case, you'll need to do this via PHP, or JavaScript

Comment: Yesh, I'm assume it's meant to be `display:initial` but it's really not clear what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: yeah url ala link -> the page you are on

Comment: and `display:normal` **IS** a `display` option. See Microsoft VS documentation

Comment: @Quest, I'm sorry, but you're wrong. I don't care what Microsoft says. W3C, the HTML/CSS standards creator, [says otherwise](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display).

Comment: @rnevius Okay then.. taking back. I trusted Microsoft and their visual studio helpers, but I did wrong I think. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done through CSS alone. One solution would be to use Javascript instead:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("modern")>-1){
    var modern=document.querySelectorAll(".modern"),x=modern.length;
    while(x--)
        modern[x].style.display="initial";
}
```

Comment: Just curious...is there any advantage to using `querySelectorAll()` here versus `getElementsByClassName()`?